# Random signls and clocktime in Simulink

Tags: matlab, random, clock

I have a problem in understanding a simple matlab property. If you have this simple model with the clock, a matlab function and a scope. Why does the fuction is just run every 0.2 seconds in the simulation time? Same when you use 100 as Stop time. Then the function will be run every 2 seconds. In between the random values generated by the funtion, Simulink connects the values linearzed. Next question is why is simulink generating alwys the same "random"signal? I want to implement a random noise signal in a bigger model, but i think i did not understand  how it works.

```
function y = fcn(u)
y  =rand;
end
```

[image]

Comment: Simulation tick time is a setting. By default, you are letting simulink chose the time step size to be variable, and it depends on what simulink thinks internally is best. You can change all this settings anytime. Similalry to the random seed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you tell me were i can set it in the Settings. Is it under Model Settings>Solver in Simulink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the solver type to [fixedstep](/questions/tagged/fixedstep) and set the timestep to whichever value you want in order to obtain the results at the desired time intervals.

Regarding the result of the [rand](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) function, you can initiate it each time with a different seed (based on the current time) by calling the [rng](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html) function before rand with the mode [shuffle](/questions/tagged/shuffle):

```
function y = fcn(u)
rng('shuffle');
y  =rand;
end
```